# push object to vector after passing through conversion function

Tags: c++, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

I desire to insert a conversion function (probably a std::function) to modify an object that is being pushed onto a std::vector.  I would like the object to construct in-place, and pass through the function without additional copies being constructed.

Let's say I'm doing this:

```
std::vector<foo> foo_array;

foo_array.push_back(foo(foo_construct_arguments...));
```

Now I want to do this:

```
foo_array.push_back(convert(foo(foo_construct_arguments...)));
```

Where 'convert' is something like this:

```
std::function<foo &(foo&)> convert{ [&](foo &f)->foo& { return f; } }
```

Obviously, the function must modify f to be useful, but in the simplest case let's say it just returns the object.

I want to end up with syntax that looks something like this:

```
foo_array.emplace_back(convert(foo(foo_construct_arguments...)));
```

And have an instance of foo constructed, modified by the convert function, then emplaced in the vector with only a single construction.  It seems like there should be some way of specifying r-value references in the proper places to get this to happen, but I'm not familiar enough with move-semantics etc. to make it happen.  I can find ways to get there with 1 copy along the way.

Comment: Why do you want to write this all in one line? You can construct the object once, modify it, and then move it into the vector.

Comment: Is there a way to get the object in the vector without a copy at that point?

Comment: `std::vector::push_back` has an overload for an rvalue reference, so you can call `push_back(std::move(modified_obj))` if you have a move constructor defined for your object

Comment: When I do this, it calls move, copy, destruct on the object???

Comment: You'r code alrady works exactly as described because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). In any case why don't you simply use [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

Comment: @Victor - The vector is being filled as data comes available, so I'm trying to apply a correction to the data as I'm filling.  This is happening on a separate thread that has time while the data is coming.  After the data has arrived, any post-analysis holds up other things that are waiting for the whole set of data.

Comment: It also looks like transform would make another copy of everything as the output, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax needed here is:

```
std::function<foo&&(foo&&)> convert{[](foo&& f) -> foo&& { return std::move(f); } };
```

Or, fully generic lambda `fn`:

```
auto fn = [](auto&& f) -> decltype(auto) { return std::forward<decltype(f)>(f); };
std::function<foo&&(foo&&)> convert{fn};
```

If this code is on a hot path, you may like to avoid wrapping a lambda into `std::function`, if possible.

---

Alternatively, [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) returns a reference to the new element, which you can then use to modify the element in-place:

```
std::vector<foo> foo_array;
std::function<void(foo&)> convert{...};
convert(foo_array.emplace_back(foo_construct_arguments...));
```

Comment: should the function signature be std::function<foo&&(foo)>???

Comment: @ttemple That's another option.

Comment: I tried it your way and I get lots of construct/copy calls?

Comment: @ttemple You should try an optimized build. However, using `std::function` precludes inlining and copy elision.